# Play a Sound When Making a Selection in Settings (Android App)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer, android-preferences

I have a settings activity in my Android app that selects a sound from a choice of files in the res/raw folder. There are other settings too but the essential part of the settings_pref.xml file is

```
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Pager Tone">

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="pager1"
        android:entries="@array/pagerName"
        android:entryValues="@array/pagerFile"
        android:key="pagerSound"
        android:title="Select Pager Tone"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Then the SettingsFragment.java is

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_pref, rootKey);
    }
}
```

Simple. And it works. Now I want to play a short sample of the sound when the user selects it. That's where I'm coming unstuck. I've been trying out various suggestions that I have found on the internet but I haven't got anything to work yet.

The best looking option I have found is to change the SettingsFragment.java to this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_pref, rootKey);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String pagerTone =  sharedPreferences.getString("pagerSound", "");
        Resources res = this.getResources();
        int soundId = res.getIdentifier(pagerTone, "raw", "cgpagerdev");
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), soundId);
        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int Volume = (int) (maxVolume * 0.2);

        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, Volume,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        player.start();
    }

}
```

I don't know if it will actually work because Android Studio gives the following error:

Cannot resolve method 'getSystemService' in 'SettingsFragment'

Following any of the suggestions from Android Studio just seems to generate other error messages. Similar code in another place works OK so I can't see what is going wrong here. I know I will have to add something to make the sound stop again (perhaps a timer to limit it to 1 or 2 seconds) but I would just like to get it working at all first.

Answer (score 1):

`getSystemService` is a method of the class `Context` [(1)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.String))

`Activity` extends `Context` so you can call the method from within an activity.
Fragment doesn't extend anything so you need to get the context by calling `getContext` or `requireContext` in your fragment and then call `getSystemService`.

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Great step forward, but it leads me to a new problem. Android Studio no longer throws a problem but going to the Settings activity crashes the app. By elimination I've found that there is a problem with the integer soundId.
The int soundId ..... line is fine, but the MediaPlayer line causes a crash. Substituting a Toast that should display the value of soundId also crashes it, so I assume that it is using soundId that causes the problem.

Comment: That's a totally different question then. Just start a new one about this issue. Are you sure the soundId is a valid identifier?

Comment: Fair point. Eventually I got a resolution with much juggling and googling, so no need for a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the resolution mentioned in my comment above only partially worked. So I will start a new question.